# Make-change: Beginner Trouble

Tags: recursion, scheme, coin-change

I'm trying to create "make-change" that will return a ls of coins whose sum = the input, and it needs to contain the least number of coins possible. 
Ex: (make-change 99)

=> (quarter quarter quarter dime dime penny penny penny penny)

Comment: If it's a homework, tag it as so. Also, use four indents to format your code.

Comment: What about the 5 cent piece - the nickel?

Comment: At first I would start with the biggest value in `cond`. And you need a condition when x reachs zero, simply return the empty list.

Comment: knivil, you're awesome, I finally got it to work!  thanks for the hint!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the lines along which `make-change` should operate:

- If the remaining amount is exactly equal to 1, 5, 10, or 25 then return the appropriate coin.
- Otherwise, `cons` the largest coin you can use onto the result of `(make-change (- x value))` where `value` is the amount of the coin that you just used.

You can tell this procedure will terminate, since the amount will become smaller and smaller via step 2 until it is finally amenable to concluding with step 1.

Comment: I'd add that I would break this up into a function that chooses the coin, and one that actually performs the algorithm, for clarity.

Comment: I agree with both Yasir and Marcin's comments.

Comment: -1. Using this approach you'd get `(quarter dime penny penny penny penny penny penny penny)` as a change of 42, while `(dime dime dime dime penny penny)` would be considerably shorter. This doesn't address the OP's question, which wants the least number of coins possible. This question clarifies the things http://stackoverflow.com/q/3947867/298282

Comment: This didn't work for me when I first tried it, but that's because I forgot my base case & I didn't start with the biggest value in cond.. But now I get it and it's working perfectly. Thanks :)