# Most optimal coin fit for a given sum of money

Tags: algorithm, combinations

How would you reach a given sum in the most optimal manner possible given a set of coins ?

Let's say that in this case we have random numbers of 1, 5, 10, 20 and 50 cent coins with the biggest coins getting the priority.

My first intuition would be to use all the biggest coins possible to fit and then use up the next smallest coin in value if the sum is exceeded.

Would this do or are there any shortfalls to this approach ? Are there any more efficient approaches ?

Comment: Have a look at http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Optimization_example:_Change_problem which explains this *exact* concept and how to use dynamic programming to solve it.

Comment: You'll first have to check if given a set of coin C (in you example C={1,5,10,20,50}) is canonical (or orderly in some articles). If it is the greedy algorithm gives the optimal answer for any given amount, if it is not then you have to fallback on dp to get the optimal answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are shortfalls to simply giving out the largest coins first.

Let's say your vending machine is out of every coin except twenty each of 50c, 20c and 1c coins and you have to deliver 60c in change.

A "prioritise-largest" (or greedy) scheme will give you eleven coins, one 50c coin and ten 1c coins.

The better solution is three 20c coins.

Greedy schemes only give you *local* optimum solutions. For global optima, you generally need to examine all possibilities (though there may be minimax-type algorithms to reduce the search space) to be certain which, for delivering change, is usually quite within the limits of computability.

Answer (score 3):

[Greedy Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) (what you are doing right now) are usually chosen for this type of things and implemented as [Final State Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to be used in vending machines (for this particular case).

> The greedy algorithm determines the minimum number of coins to give
>   while making change. These are the steps a human would take to emulate
>   a greedy algorithm

Comment: It's worth noting, this does assume the coin denominations are intelligently chosen - as they usually are in real-world currencies. This fails to produce the best option in case of *random* denominations (see @paxdiablo's example of 50c/20c/1c).

Comment: @lc: Indeed. That is a limitation of the greedy algorithm. I brought the example of vending machines since they usually deal relatively small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption to exhaust largest denomination will not be the best solution each time. Example:

```
Input: coins[] = {25, 10, 5}, V = 30
Output: Minimum 2 coins required
We can use one coin of 25 cents and one of 5 cents 

Input: coins[] = {9, 6, 5, 1}, V = 11
Output: Minimum 2 coins required
We can use one coin of 6 cents and 1 coin of 5 cents (min)
As per logic of exhausting largest coins first, we would end up with one
coin of 9 cents and 2 coins of 1 cent
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947867/find-the-least-number-of-coins-required-that-can-make-any-change-from-1-to-99-ce#answer-3950059) for more clarification.