# Find the smallest number of coins for a number

Tags: java, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most optimal coin fit for a given sum of money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667721/most-optimal-coin-fit-for-a-given-sum-of-money)

I'm going over some practice interview questions and this one has always puzzled me.  Here's the question:

> Given coins 1c, 7c, 13c, and 19c return a String with the smallest number of coins needed         > to represent an input of X.

Now, I've solved this easily before when it was in easy denominations like 1c, 5c, 10c, and 25c.  That's just a simple greedy algorithm.  For this I'm thinking it would be some sort of permutation problem, but I'm not sure how to get the minimum.  Any ideas?  Here's some pseudocode that I have:

```
String coinDenominations(double amount, String coins)
{
    if(amount > .19) coinDenominations(amount - .19, coins + "19 ");
    if(amount > .13) coinDenominations(amount - .13, coins + "13 ");
    if(amount > .07) coinDenominations(amount - .07, coins + "7 ");
    if(amount > .01) coinDenominations(amount - .01, coins + "1 ");
    if(amount == 0) System.out.println(coins);
}
```

I'm rusty with permutations, but I think that would output the possible combinations.  How would I find the smallest amount though?  Is there a better non-recursive way to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667721/most-optimal-coin-fit-for-a-given-sum-of-money/12667766#12667766

Comment: This can be solved using Dynamic Programming

Comment: @paxdiablo So it looks like I'm right that the permutations method is the right way to go.  Is there any way to efficiently find the smallest number of permutations though?  I'm sure that's been answered on SO so I will refine my search.

Comment: We can't do your work (i.e. writing the code for you). I'll give you a nice topic on this, explaining the 3rd as the best solution using dynamic programming: [The Coin Problem](http://www.seeingwithc.org/topic1html.html).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for the link.  Very interesting algorithm, will try to reproduce in Java. :)

Comment: To those who voted this a dupe, I think you're wrong, simply because the denominations are different. Whilst a 1/5/10/20/50 from the other question renders the greedy algorithm incorrect for some values, that is not the case here with 1/7/13/19. The denominations, and specifically the relationships between them, are _very_ important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667721/most-optimal-coin-fit-for-a-given-sum-of-money/12667766#12667766), certain coin combinations may lend themselves to a greedy algorithm but it's not guaranteed that greediness will give you the best mix for all coin combinations.

An exhaustive, recursive solution in Python (an ideal language for pseudo-code) follows.

Note that this gives you permutations rather than combinations but, if you wanted to filter out duplicates (in terms of combinations), it would be simple to sort and filter after the list is created.

Note also that it's likely to be rather horrendous for larger amounts. For example, while it's well under a second for input values like 27 or 75, an input of 1024 takes at least a couple of minutes before I get bored and cancel it).

```
import sys

oldcount = 99999999
lst = []

def recurse (str, amt, count):
    global oldcount
    global lst
    if amt < 0: return
    if count > oldcount: return
    if amt == 0:
        if count < oldcount:
            print "====="
            lst = []
            oldcount = count
        if count == oldcount:
            lst.append (str)
        return
    recurse ("%s 19" % str, amt - 19, count + 1)
    recurse ("%s 13" % str, amt - 13, count + 1)
    recurse ("%s  7" % str, amt -  7, count + 1)
    recurse ("%s  1" % str, amt -  1, count + 1)

recurse ("", int (sys.argv[1]), 0)
#for seq in lst: print seq
print "%d permutations" % len (lst)
```

---

Note that, for the denominations `{1, 7, 13, 19}` (this particular case), the greedy algorithm *is* the best, the "proof" of that follows <sup>(a)</sup>:

For any value 1 through 6, you *have* to use that many `1` coins, which is what the greedy algorithm gives you.

For any value 7 through 12, you can either use that many `1` coins or a `7` with seven less `1` coins. The greedy algorithm gives you the latter case, which is correct, because it's better to take away seven `1` coins and add a single `7` coin - it drops the coin count by six.

For values 13 through 18, you can't use a `13` and a `7` since that will be a minimum of `20` so you're stuck with a `13/1` mix or a `7/1` mix (all `1` coins is out for the same reason it was in the previous paragraph - swapping 13 `1` coins for a single `13` coin is a massive decrease). Obviously, the best bet for a 13 value is a single `13` coin, but 14 can be achieved with either `7/7` or `13/1` (both two coins). Then values 15 through 18 simply have `1` coins added.

Similarly, a 19 value is the single coin `19` while a 20 value can be represented by `19/1` or `13/7`. Values from 21 through 37 (just before the `19/19` value of 38) are `19` plus the minimal mix from the previous three paragraphs.

So, because of the values chosen (`1` and `7` are disparate, `7/7` == `13/1`, `7/7/7` == `19/1/1`, `13/7` == `19/1` and so on), the greedy algorithm works just fine (I don't believe those values were chosen randomly by the way, it's just too convenient).

The table of minimal coin counts follows:

```
Value  Count  Possibilities
    1      1  1
    2      2  1x2
    3      3  1x3
    4      4  1x4
    5      5  1x5
    6      6  1x6
    7      1  7
    8      2  7,1
    9      3  7,1x2
    :
   12      6  7,1x5
   13      1  13
   14      2  13,1 or 7x2
   15      2  13,1x2 or 7x2,1
    :
   18      6  13,1X5 or 7x2,1x4
   19      1  19
   20      2  19,1 or 13,7
   21      3  19,1x2 or 13,7,1 or 7x3
    :
```

and so on.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Not a *formal* proof but I'm so certain I'm right that I'll upvote 20 questions/answers to the first person who shows me a counter-example (providing the questions and answers aren't complete rubbish of course - I have to think they're useful so as to not corrupt the voting process).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to touch back on this.  Another neat solution I found was to parse all of the permutations into a tree and then do a breadth-first search to find the first leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done like this.

Amount is x. coins are 1c,7c,13c & 19c.

the algorithm is as follows.

x = x*100;

need_19 = x/19;

y = x%19;

need_13 = y/13;

y = y%13;

need_7 = y/7;

y = y%7;

need_1 = y;

total_coins = need_19 + need_13 + need_7 + +need_1;

Comment: Please see the link in my comment on OP's question. This is the naive way to solve the problem and it won't give you the best result. Also, try to change the coin systems (1,2,5,10 to 1,2,5,10,20,50) and you see that the algorithm and the results will be very different (and really hard to maintain).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Would you mind elaborating a bit about why this would not give the best result? Also, by using different denominations of coins, the result might be different too. Why is that a problem? The coin denominations and the sum to divide are the input parameters to this algorithm, and the output parameter is connected to the input parameters in some way isn't it? Also, why would maintaining this cycle difficult? It just needs an array of coin denominations, then process them in descending order. A different set of coins is just a different input. I don't see your point!

Comment: @ppeterka you can verify this link provided by '@LuiggiMendoza' -- http://www.seeingwithc.org/topic1html.html

Comment: @QATest : I violated one of my basic rules: never write before coffee, just read... Now I think I drink that coffee before I do something stupid again...

Answer (score 0):

I think we can write something like this:

```
String coinDenominations(double amount){
   int[] coinDenom = new int[] {19,13,7,1};
   int amountInCents = amount*100;
   String coinDenomString = "";
   for(int i=0; i< coinDenom.length; i++){
       coinDenomString = coinDenomString + ((int)(amountInCents/coinDenom[i])) 
                         + "of +"  coinDenom[i] + "coins";
       amountInCents = amountInCents % coinDenom[i];
   }
   return coinDenomString;
}
```

I believe, **above can be converted to recursion as well.**