# Least Coin Used Algorithm Java

Tags: java, int

I am stuck on the coin denomination problem.

I am trying to find the lowest number of coins used to make up $5.70 (or 570 cents). For example, if the coin array is {100,5,2,5,1} (100 x 10c coins, 5 x 20c, 2 x 50c, 5 x $1, and 1 x $2 coin), then the result should be {0,1,1,3,1}
At the moment the coin array will consist of the same denominations ( $2, $1, 50c, 20c, 10c)

```
public static int[] makeChange(int change, int[] coins) {

    // while you have coins of that denomination left and the total
    // remaining amount exceeds that denomination, take a coin of that
    // denomination (i.e add it to your result array, subtract it from the
    // number of available coins, and update the total remainder). –

    for(int i= 0; i< coins.length; i++){
    while (coins[i] > 0) {

        if (coins[i] > 0 & change - 200 >= 0) {

            coins[4] = coins[4]--;
            change = change - 200;

        } else 

        if (coins[i] > 0 & change - 100 >= 0) {

            coins[3] = coins[3]--;
            change = change - 100;

        } else

        if (coins[i] > 0 & change - 50 >= 0) {

            coins[2] = coins[2]--;
            change = change - 50;

        } else

        if (coins[i] > 0 & change - 20 >= 0) {

            coins[1] = coins[1]--;
            change = change - 20;

        } else

        if (coins[i] > 0 & change - 10 >= 0) {

            coins[0] = coins[0]--;
            change = change - 10;

        }
    }

    }
    return coins;

}
```

I am stuck on how to deduct the values from coins array and return it.

EDIT: New code

Comment: Here is an (unoptimized) algorithm: for each denomination, while you have coins of that denomination left _and_ the total remaining amount exceeds that denomination, take a coin of that denomination (i.e add it to your result array, subtract it from the number of available coins, and update the total remainder).

Comment: You are not in the right direction, you have a problem which is NP-Complete, and there is no known polynomial solution to it. However, for the case where you have infinity of each coin, there is a pseudo polynomial solution, and this is known as the [Change Making Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). I do not know if you can adjust the pseudo-polynomial solution for a limited number of each coin.

Comment: (1) Your edit still won't work. You cannot solve this problem so efficiently I am afraid (2) What do you think happens in `coins[4] = coins[4]--;` - It's a really bad practice to assign and change a value in the same expression, just change this to `coins[4]--;`?

Comment: Still doesnt work though =( can someone please post some code as I am not sure how else I can understand it.

Comment: @user3353723 Did you read my comment? Of course it won't work. Read the link I gave you, it should give you some insights.

Comment: @user3353723  You keep saying "someone post some code".  Do you want to understand how to solve the problem or not?

Comment: I do understand the problem but struggling to put it in code. I did give it a good attempt and after an hour I decided to ask for help.

Comment: @user3353723 and we helped, we provided you a link to a wikipedia article that explains a variant of your problem. Read it. Understand it. Then come back and ask questions.

Comment: @amit, I believe this set of coin in OP's example is [canonical](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/when-can-a-greedy-algorithm-solve-the-coin-change-problem), which can be solved greedily.

Comment: I agree with @PhamTrung. That means that you can start by taking from the largest denomination until you're finished, run out of that denomination or the difference between your current value and target is less that that denomination. Then do the same thing for the second largest denomination.

Comment: I don't think greedy works if the number of coins of different kinds is limited, even if the denominations are otherwise *canonical*. Let me rephrase that: I don't think all *canonical* denominations can be solved optimally by greedy if limits are imposed on the number of coins of each kind. It might work for a OPs set of denominations, and for a subset of *canonical* denominations.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force solution is to try up to the available number of coins of the highest denomination (stopping when you run out or the amount would become negative) and for each of these recurse on solving the remaining amount with a shorter list that excludes that denomination, and pick the minimum of these. If the base case is 1c the problem can always be solved, and the base case is `return n` otherwise it is `n/d0` (`d0` representing the lowest denomination), but care must be taken to return a large value when not evenly divisible so the optimization can pick a different branch. Memoization is possible, and parameterized by the remaining amount and the next denomination to try. So the memo table size would be is `O(n*d)`, where `n` is the starting amount and `d` is the number of denominations.

So the problem can be solved in *pseudo-polynomial* time.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) is sparse on details on how to decide if a greedy algorithm such as yours will work. A better reference is linked in this [CS StackExchange question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/when-can-a-greedy-algorithm-solve-the-coin-change-problem). Essentially, if the coin system is *canonical*, a greedy algorithm will provide an optimal solution. So, is [1, 2, 5, 10, 20] canonical? (using 10s of cents for units, so that the sequence starts in 1)

According to [this article](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0809/0809.0400v1.pdf), a 5-coin system is *non*-canonical if and only if it satisfies exactly one of the following conditions:

- [1, c2, c3] is non-canonical (false for [1, 2, 5])
- it cannot be written as [1, 2, c3, c3+1, 2*c3] (true for [1, 2, 5, 10, 20])
- the greedyAnswerSize((k+1) * c4) > k+1 with k*c4 < c5 < (k+1) * c4; in this case, this would require a k*10 < 20 < (k+1)*10; there is no integer k in that range, so this is false for [1, 2, 5, 10, 20].

Therefore, since the greedy algorithm will not provide optimal answers (and even if it did, I doubt that it would work with limited coins), you should try dynamic programming or some enlightened backtracking:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {

    public static class Answer implements Comparable<Answer> {
        public static final int coins[] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20};

        private int availableCoins[] = new int[coins.length];
        private int totalAvailable;
        private int totalRemaining;
        private int coinsUsed;

        public Answer(int availableCoins[], int totalRemaining) {
            for (int i=0; i<coins.length; i++) {
                this.availableCoins[i] = availableCoins[i];
                totalAvailable += coins[i] * availableCoins[i];
            }
            this.totalRemaining = totalRemaining;
        }

        public boolean hasCoin(int coinIndex) { 
            return availableCoins[coinIndex] > 0; 
        }

        public boolean isPossibleBest(Answer oldBest) {
            boolean r = totalRemaining >= 0
                && totalAvailable >= totalRemaining
                && (oldBest == null || oldBest.coinsUsed > coinsUsed);
            return r;
        }

        public boolean isAnswer() {
            return totalRemaining == 0;
        }

        public Answer useCoin(int coinIndex) {
            Answer a = new Answer(availableCoins, totalRemaining - coins[coinIndex]);
            a.availableCoins[coinIndex]--;
            a.totalAvailable = totalAvailable - coins[coinIndex];
            a.coinsUsed = coinsUsed+1;
            return a;
        }

        public int getCoinsUsed() {
            return coinsUsed;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            for (int c : availableCoins) sb.append(c + ",");            
            sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-1, '}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        // try to be greedy first
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Answer a) {
            int r = totalRemaining - a.totalRemaining;
            return (r==0) ? coinsUsed - a.coinsUsed : r;
        }
    }        

    // returns an minimal set of coins to solve
    public static int makeChange(int change, int[] availableCoins) {
        PriorityQueue<Answer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Answer>();
        queue.add(new Answer(availableCoins, change));
        HashSet<String> known = new HashSet<String>();
        Answer best = null;
        int expansions = 0;
        while ( ! queue.isEmpty()) {
            Answer current = queue.remove();            
            expansions ++;
            String s = current.toString();
            if (current.isPossibleBest(best) && ! known.contains(s)) {
                known.add(s);
                if (current.isAnswer()) {
                    best = current;
                } else {
                    for (int i=0; i<Answer.coins.length; i++) {
                        if (current.hasCoin(i)) {
                            queue.add(current.useCoin(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // debug
        System.out.println("After " + expansions + " expansions");
        return (best != null) ? best.getCoinsUsed() : -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Solving for " + i + ":"
                + makeChange(i, new int[]{100,5,2,5,1}));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in wrong direction. This program will not give you an optimal solution. To get optimal solution go with dynamic algorithms implemented and discussed here. Please visit these few links:

1. [link 1](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/DynProg/money-change.html)
2. [link 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31002/Coin-Change-Problem-Using-Dynamic-Programming)
3. [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947867/find-the-least-number-of-coins-required-that-can-make-any-change-from-1-to-99-ce)

Comment: Those links address a different problem. Here the number of coins of each kind is limited.

Comment: I adviced him for just having a look on those links to get an idea. I haven't told that there is an answer code for his problem. A down vote, its....

Comment: Hm, I thought the rules are, if you don't have an actual answer, stick to commenting.

Comment: due to less than 50 repo. I can't comment on other posts. Min 50 is req.

Comment: Lol, so answer different questions, but yeah that aspect of SO kind of sucks -- sorry, I didn't notice.