# How to choose the least number of weights to get a total weight in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm

If there are `n` unsorted weights and I need to find the least number of weights to get at least weight `W`. 
How do I find them in `O(n)`?

Comment: is there a limit on the weights ?

Comment: please, Example data - so we can check it. Example output on that data. And your attempt at coding a solution?

Comment: This can be done with quickselect.

Comment: Sounds like a bin packing problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem Or maybe knapsack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: This is not "too broad" by any stretch of imagination. Shows little own work? Yes. But not "broad". Reopen.

Comment: @cricket_007 it is not knapsack nor packing problem. Sounds similar but is in fact much easier.

Comment: @n.m, just curious, you have a link to something that explains why it is easier than 'knapsack'?

Comment: @RyanVincent I have a working O(n) algorithm, but O(n log n) is absolutely trivial. Just sort them and take the heaviest ones until you hit W. It is easy to show that any smaller number cannot be a solution.

Comment: @n.m, that makes sense - I didn't read the question as carefully as I should have.

Comment: @n.m. How can it be done using quickselect? Which k^th smallest element we are looking for? And isn't quickselect runs in O(n^2) at worst case, anyway?

Comment: @errorist When partitioning, keep track of total weight that go to to the right of the median. Then partition the right half or the left part depending on whether the total is more or less than W.

Comment: Is this similar to the least number of coins problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947867/find-the-least-number-of-coins-required-that-can-make-any-change-from-1-to-99-ce

Comment: @Twinkle Rolledback as you changed the whole question.  If you want to ask another question please open a new one instead of editing this. In addition, if you find one of the answers below acceptable please consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi @Twinkle,  If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Is `W` a fixed constant or an input to the function? If an input, would an answer with complexity `O(n + n*w^2)` be acceptable? It's linear in `n` but not linear.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7746648/56778

Answer (score 3):

This problem has many solution methods:

**Method 1 - Sorting - O(nlogn)**
I guess that the most trivial one would be to sort in descending order and then to take the first K elements that give a sum of at least W. The time complexity will be though `O(nlogn)`.

**Method 2 - Max Heap - O(n + klogn)**
Another method would be to use a max heap.
Creating the heap will take `O(n)` and then extracting elements until we got to a total sum of at least W. Each extraction will take `O(logn)` so the total time complexity will be `O(klogn)` where `k` is the number of elements we had to extract from the heap.

**Method 3 - Using Min Heap - O(nlogk)**
Adding this method that [JimMischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778) suggested in the comments below.
Creating a min heap with the first `k` elements in the list that sums to at least `W`. Then, iterate over the remaining elements and if it's greater than the minimum (heap top) replace between them.
At this point, it might be that we have more elements of what we actually need to get to `W`, so we will just extract the minimums until we reach our limit. In practice, depending on the relation between

```
find_min_set(A,W)
    currentW = 0
    heap H //Create empty heap

    for each Elem in A
        if (currentW < W)
            H.add(Elem)
            currentW += Elem
        else if (Elem > H.top())
            currentW += (Elem-H.top())
            H.pop()
            H.add(Elem)

    while (currentW-H.top() > W)
        currentW -= H.top()
        H.pop()
```

This method might be even faster in practice, depending on the relation between `k` and `n`. See [when theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/).

**Method 4 - O(n)**
The best method I could think of will be using some kind of [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) while keeping track of the total weight and always partitioning with the median as a pivot.

First, let's define few things:

`sum(A)` - The total sum of all elements in array `A`.
`num(A)` - The number of elements in array `A`.
`med(A)` - The median of the array `A`.

```
find_min_set(A,W,T)
    //partition A
    //L contains all the elements of A that are less than med(A)
    //R contains all the elements of A that are greater or equal to med(A)
    L, R = partition(A,med(A))
    if (sum(R)==W)
        return T+num(R)
    if (sum(R) > W)
        return find_min_set(R,W,T)
    if (sum(R) < W)
        return find_min_set(L,W-sum(R),num(R)+T)
```

Calling this method by `find_min_set(A,W,0)`.

Runtime Complexity:

- Finding median is `O(n)`.
- Partitioning is `O(n)`.
- Each recursive call is taking half of the size of the array.
- Summing it all up we get a follow relation: `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)` which is same as the average case of quickselect = `O(n)`.

**Note:** When all values are unique both worst-case and average complexity is indeed `O(n)`. With possible duplicates values, the average complexity is still `O(n)` but the worst case is `O(nlogn)` with using [Median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) method for selecting the pivot.

Comment: @trincot That would be true if you were looking for a set with weight *exactly* `W`, but if you just want *at least* `W`, greedily selecting the largest remaining element is what you want. Methods 1 and 2 are fine; method 3 works, but I don't think its running time is any more bounded than method 2's.

Comment: Ah yes, @chepner, I now see the title of the question is somewhat misleading. I took it to mean *exactly*, which turns out not to be what is asked. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @chepner I think it does. Choosing the median is O(n), partitioning is O(n). And by choosing the median it promises that each recursion is being called with half of the size of the array, meaning it promises the runtime of the average case of quickselect which is O(n). Am I missing something?

Comment: Partitioning on the median only spits the array if you have *unique* elements. Quicksort and quickselect both require choosing a random pivot element to avoid worst-case behavior; I suspect this might as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians probably works, though.

Comment: @chepner: You can't solve the problems of highly-duplicate elements with pivot selection. For example, the case of an entire array of duplicates will cause bad behavior with any pivot selection process unless you have additional special handling for duplicates.

Comment: The heap method can be done in `O(k + n log k)`. There's no need to create a heap of all the items. Just create a min-heap of the first k items. Then for each of the remaining items in the list, replace the minimum item in the heap if the list item is larger than that minimum item. This can be *much* faster than the O(n) method if k is very small compared to n. If k is less than 1% of n, then heap select is probably going to be faster than quickselect. Picking the top 100 from 100,000, for example. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/

Comment: @JimMischel Nice solution. Haven't thought about it. I guess that I will add it as another method. You are right, the method you choose in practice has to take into account the sizes of the input. (i.e. the ratio between *k* and *n*). Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @JimMischel After taking a closer look at this. The question is about getting at least weight `W`. You don't know what is your `k`. Isn't that a problem with your suggestion?

Comment: @A.Sarid: No, not at all. It's the same problem as described here: stackoverflow.com/q/7746648/56778

Comment: @JimMischel Now I get it. Added as another method. Thanks.